# Laravel Reproduce an array given by the eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am new in laravel. Right now i am struggling on how to redeclare the array given by the eloquent model.

PHP code

```
$data = Commission::select(['uploads_id'])->where([
            'affiliate_code' => $id
        ])->get()->toArray();
        var_dump($data);
```

var_dump Output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["uploads_id"]=>
    string(2) "24"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["uploads_id"]=>
    string(2) "26"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["uploads_id"]=>
    string(2) "27"
  }
}
```

i want the `$data` to be redeclare like this.

```
$data = [24 , 25 , 26]
```

is there a way on it or different approach?

Comment: Try passing the field in the get method as an array. get(['uploads_id'])

Comment: @ShubhamoyChakrabarty output is still the same

Comment: Using a foreach statement build your new array

Comment: Can you show me how to?

Comment: Define an empty array after that run a foreach statement. On each iteration append the value from your $data['uploads_id'] to the empty array.

Comment: `$data2 = array();
        foreach ($data as $i) {
            $data2[] = $i;
        }`

i am doing it wrong? coz i doesn't output what i want to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call get() method on Laravel Builder Object, it will return a Collection Object to you. And there are so many nice helpers you can use instead of getting your hands dirty with php array. You can find references [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections).

In your scenario, this can be done by

```
Commission::select(['uploads_id'])->where([
    'affiliate_id' => $id
])->get()->pluck('uploads_id');
```

Pluck() is a Collection method and it's documentation can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-pluck). Remember to cast it to php array with ->all() or ->toArray(). It's useful to be familiar with Collection in Laravel.

Good luck!

Comment: Wow! This is what i want. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
$data = Commission::select(['uploads_id'])
            ->where(['affiliate_code' => $id])
            ->lists('uploads_id')
            ->toArray();


print_r($data);
```